# How to know which API Partner Server URL to use

Tags: api, soap-api, connected-apps

I have registered an development test account in SF and one connected app.
From connected app I have to call SF SOAP API. I do not know which web service base address to use. I see that for different environments there are different URL addresses, such as Api.Partner_Server_URL_160 Api.Partner_Server_URL_210 and others.

How to know which one URL environment to use ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version number (e.g. 160, 210) references the version of the API being used (e.g. 16.0, 21.0). This is influenced by when the app was originally developed or last updated to the latest version of the API. When creating a new app, you will generally use the latest possible version available at that time (e.g. 29.0), because you cannot intentionally download a WSDL for an older version. Versioning is how salesforce.com can keep introducing new features while maintaining backwards compatibility. In summary, if you have any doubt, check the version of the imported WSDL file; that is the version you will use.